# Regular expression to remove default ID's from ASP.NET tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2010

We have a custom set of custom control tags, eg:

```
<ourTag:OurControl runat="server" />
```

Throughout our project we have discovered Visual Studio's marvelous(sarcasm) helper which automatically pastes an ID with the tags name followed by a counter number.

I am now trying to remove them globally.

I believe I can do this via regular expressions in VS find/replace functionality.  Here is my current expression:

```
<ourTag\:([a-z]*[0-9]+?).*ID=\"\1\"
```

This is not working and I am having trouble working out the correct way of doing this.

What do I need to do to make this work correctly?

I have had a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: you want to customize ID in code or generated HTML...? you have written in Code but still wanted to clarify

Comment: I want to remove the default ID that Visual Studio automatically generates. They screw with our jQuery requests.

Comment: @Russel: with the id removed, what id is placed on the elements?

Comment: @John - as part of our framework the ID is generated inside our overridden UserControl.Render method.  Essentially we ignore the auto-generated ID field, but it can be confusing as to what ID is actually rendering.

Comment: @Russell: I think you should probably have the designer of your custom controls generate the ID they want. That way, you'll get the best of both worlds - whichever ID you like, plus other controls on the design surface will be able to reference your control by id.

Comment: Yeah but in this case the auto-generated ID's would override our ID values. Our design is not perfect (and not recent) but it stands fast and has a good repuatation for previous projects. This is a tidy thing for us at the moment. It would be nice if we could turn the functionality off in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Eureka!

use this for the Find What:

```
ourtags\:{[a-zA-Z]*}{.*}{ID=\"\1[0-9]+\"}
```

use this for Replace With:

```
ourtags\:\1\2
```